# Geometric description of the span

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am doing a question on Linear combinations to revise for a linear algebra test. I  do not have access to the solutions therefore I am not sure if I am corrects or if my intuitions are correct, also I am stuck in a few places. Would be great if someone can help me out.

$u = (1,2,1)$ and $v=(2,-1,0)$

1) The vector $w$ is a linear combination of the vectors ${u, v}$ if:

$w = au + bv,$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{R} $ (is this correct?)

2) The span of two vectors $u, v ∈ \mathbb{R}^3$ is the set of vectors:

span{u,v} = {a(1,2,1) + b(2,-1,0)} (is this correct?)

3) Write down a geometric description of the span of two vectors $u, v ∈ \mathbb{R}^3$.

I dont understand what is required here. Please help.

4) Is it possible to find two vectors whose span is a plane that does not pass through the origin? If not, explain why not. If so, find two vectors that achieve this.

Same as three. I have no idea.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Is correct, see the definition of linear combination

2) Yes, maybe you'll see the notation $\langle\{u,v\}\rangle$ for the span of $u$ and $v$
and it's definition

$$ \langle\{u,v\}\rangle = \left\{w\in \mathbb{R}^3\; : \; w = a u+bv, \; \; a,b\in\mathbb{R} \right\}$$

3) The span of two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$

- if $\{u,v\}$ is a linear dependent set, then $\langle\{u,v\}\rangle$ is a line
- if $\{u,v\}$ is a linear independent set, then  $\langle\{u,v\}\rangle$ is a plane

4) No, the span of $u,v$ is a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and every vector space contains the zero vector, in this case $(0,0,0)$